# What was the point of Bran warging into the ravens during S8E3?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I still don't understand what exactly he was hoping to accomplish during that scene where

> Theon fights to protect him,

because it looked like nothing of any major significance happened besides warging into a flock of ravens for a minute and then tapping back in.

Comment: Well, it's not like he could do something else. He is not a figther, and just had to wait for NK, better do something while waiting, be it scout with ravens to see how the battle is going, or any other thing we don't see on screen

Comment: Related: [What is Bran doing in S08E03?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99919/49)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## We Do Not <s>Sow</s> Know

We can, however, rule out that he was scouting the battlefield because they fly right past the Night King and out of the area. I will speculate though that he was sending for help. He has two allies nearish by that could help: the Reeds and the Greyjoy’s. I would assume he sent help to the Reeds, they are closer and it would make for some good story telling with Meera coming back. And of course they are now in dire need of reinforcements.

It’s worth pointing out that he wasn’t warging into the ravens for a few seconds, he only stops when the Night King has approached him so he’s doing it for longer than you remember.

Comment: Talking about allies, Edmure might be there at the Twins as well or maybe in Riverrun. He's listed as a cast in s08

Comment: @KharoBangdo Do we know if Edmure was at the Twins when Arya went there or if the Lannisters had moved him though?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot he was a prisoner at Twins as claimed by Walder during the feast where Jaime is present

Comment: @KharoBangdo Aye but he could, potentially, have been moved since. It is a good theory as well though.

Comment: The ravens approach the Night King while he's on a dragon, so it's not depicting the moment he faces Bran in the godswood. Also, while Bran might (choose) not know this, is it not fairly clear Meera's dead?

Comment: @Thom All evidence suggests Meera is still alive

Answer (score 5):

Up until that point, we had not seen the Night King in the battle anywhere. None of the viewers know where the king is. Bran used the birds to find out where the king is at-presumably to gauge how long he has until their showdown. They made it a point to not show the king until then-and I know at my house we were waiting for that ice dragon to start fighting....

In a way, he's using the birds as a jedi would use the force to know when danger is nearby. By keeping tabs on the king now, he can now watch him, to see if things are going according to the future plan.

Answer (score -7):

He is

> taunting the Night King and showing his position to it. The Night King's priority is to kill Bran to destroy the memory of humanity, so what Bran did was simply "Oh, dude, I'm here, come get me"

It seems to be the most common theory on line, too.

Comment: The Night King knows where Bran is without Bran having to tell him and Bran is warging for longer than we see the ravens flying. Also Bran is not the sort to do this.

Comment: He doesn't deserve down-votes for this.  It's possible Bran is attempting to annoy the Night's King to provoke a vindictive (not well strategized) response.